# How can I add decimal places to a TimeSpan object's totalseconds?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a function which returns seconds since epoch:

```
public static string getEpochSeconds()
{
   TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
   var timestamp = t.TotalSeconds;
   return timestamp.ToString();
}
```

It outputs, for example: **1373689200.79987** but for the purposes of my application, I need it to output one more decimal place digit - for example **1373689200.799873**. How is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
return String.Format("{0}", timestamp.TotalSeconds);
```

and then you can use the format string. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for formatting information.

**Edit 1:**

Thanks @MortenMertner for the correct format.

Try using:

```
return String.Format("{0:N6}", timestamp.TotalSeconds);
```

to force 6 decimal places.

**Edit 2:**

You can lookup [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to work out the best way to do this.

One way is to use `F` instead of `N` (both of which are [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)). `N` will comma delimit the thousands where `F` will not.

```
return String.Format("{0:F6}", timestamp.TotalSeconds);
```

**Edit 3:**

As @sa_ddam213 points out in his answer, the standard `ToString()` method has an overload that accepts a formatting parameter. [MSDN documents it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) for a `Double` and you can clearly see that it accepts a [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) or a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) so @sa_daam213's answer works out quite well too and is very similar to your original code but instead of `N6` use `F6` like in my *Edit 2* above.

Comment: Use {0:N6} to force six decimal places.

Comment: i like this but it adds commas to the number. how can i prevent that?

Comment: @blizz Use `ToString("0.000000")` instead.

Answer (score 4):

you can use    `timestamp.ToString("0.000000")`

if you need result without rounding value

```
return t.TotalSeconds.ToString("F0")+"." +t.ToString("ffffff");
```

Comment: this just adds a zero to the end

Comment: @blizz it is not adding Zero, only rounding up to 6 decimal points

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add `N6` (6 decimal places) to your `ToString()`

Example:

```
public static string getEpochSeconds()
{
    TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    var timestamp = t.TotalSeconds;
    return timestamp.ToString("N6");
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that would be possible but neither TimeSpan nor the Double have a `ToString()` method that accepts parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx

Comment: @nonsensical, `Double` and `TimeSpan` both have `ToString` that accept format?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tostring.aspx

Comment: Blond moment, you're correct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tostring.aspx In which case, I prefer your solution. Vote up.

Answer (score 1):

If the last digit is not significant you can use the `ToString("N6")` (just adds a 0 at the end in this case). But if you want the real last digit, due to some strange way of converting doubles to string by .NET you may need something like the following.

```
    public static string getEpochSeconds()
    {
        TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        //t {15901.03:57:53.6052183}    System.TimeSpan
        var timestamp1 = t.TotalSeconds;
        //timestamp1    1373860673.6052184  double
        var tstring1 = timestamp1.ToString("N6");
        //tstring1  "1,373,860,673.605220"  string
        var timestamp = (long)(t.TotalSeconds * 1000000);
        //timestamp 1373860673605218    long
        string tstring =timestamp.ToString();
        //tstring   "1373860673605218"  string
        tstring = tstring.Substring(0, tstring.Length - 6) + "." + tstring.Substring(tstring.Length - 6);
        //tstring   "1373860673.605218" string
        return tstring;
    }
```

I have added the outputs also as a comment. Hope this helps.